# Renormalization constant in unstable particle propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, propagator, stability, self-energy

On Peskin & Schroeder's QFT, section 7.3, the book discusses the unstable particle.

Before (7.57), the book gives the formula of a scalar particle propagator

[image]

For unstable particle, the book defines the particle's mass by condition
$$ m^2-m_0^2-\operatorname{Re} M^2\left(m^2\right)=0 \tag{7.58}$$
Then the book says "the pole in the propagator is displaced from real axis"

[image]

I can understand the renormalization constant $Z$ in the numerator, but I don't understand why the same $Z$ appear in the denominator before $\text{Im}M^2(p^2)$?

Is this the result of renormalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$p^2 -m_0^2 - M^2(p^2)= p^2 -m_0^2 - {\rm Re}\,  M^2(p^2) -i \, {\rm Im} \, M^2(p^2)$$
$$= p^2 - m_0^2 - \left[ {\rm Re} \, M^2(m^2) +(p^2 -m^2) \frac{\partial}{\partial p^2} {\rm Re} \,M^2(p^2){\Large|}_{p^2 = m^2} + \ldots \right]-i {\rm Im }\, M^2(p^2)   $$ $$\sim (p^2 -m^2) \left(1- \frac{\partial}{\partial p^2} {\rm Re} \,  M^2(p^2) {\Large|}_{p^2 = m^2}\right) -i\,  {\rm Im} \, M^2(p^2)= Z^{-1}(p^2-m^2)- i \, {\rm Im} \, M^2(p^2)$$ $$= Z^{-1} \left(p^2 - m^2 -i \,Z \,  {\rm Im} \, M^2(p^2) \right)$$ solves your problem.